# How to relocate MyLocationView in Mapbox Android SDK?

Tags: android, mapbox

I want to change the location of `MyLocationView` in `MapView` of [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/). I don't want to use a custom marker. Because calculating bearing and adding this to a marker (like in navigation apps) is difficult for me(Sensor Fusion & GPS bearing should be done) and also `MyLocationView` is smoother than a marker in relocating and changing bearing operations. I'm continuing with Mapbox `MyLocationView`. I have done bearing tracking integration and showing location on the `MapView`. What i have done is:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        map = mapboxMap;

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getTrackingSettings().setMyLocationTrackingMode(MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW);
        map.getTrackingSettings().setMyBearingTrackingMode(MyBearingTracking.COMPASS);
        map.getTrackingSettings().setDismissBearingTrackingOnGesture(false);
        map.getMyLocationViewSettings().setForegroundDrawable(iconDrawable, iconDrawable);
        map.getMyLocationViewSettings().setBackgroundTintColor(Color.parseColor("#56B881"));
        map.getMyLocationViewSettings().setForegroundTintColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        map.getMyLocationViewSettings().setAccuracyTintColor(Color.parseColor("#56B881"));
    }
});
```

My View:
[image]

So i want to ask is it possible to update MyLocationView's Location in Mapbox Android SDK? I do lots of search but i can not figure out that. Maybe there is a trick about this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should implement ProgressChangeListener in your Activity from this package
**com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.listeners.ProgressChangeListener**
After that in the next overrided method you can update your location

```
@Override
public void onProgressChange(Location location, RouteProgress 
routeProgress) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onProgressChange" + location);
    Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChange: fraction of route traveled: %f" 
    + routeProgress.getFractionTraveled());
    if(mapboxMap.getMyLocation()!=null){  
         mapboxMap.getMyLocation().setLatitude(location.getLatitude());       
         mapboxMap.getMyLocation().setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

And for **userOffRoute** method from implemented **OffRouteListener** you can do the same.

Also I'd like to notice that in **build.gradle** I have next dependencies

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-ui:2.1.3'
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.1.3'
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:2.1.3'
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.3.1'
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-java-core:2.1.3'
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-java-geojson:2.1.3'
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-java-services:2.1.3'
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-java-services-rx:2.1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use listener and it works well

```
mapboxMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

private MapboxMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new MapboxMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(@Nullable Location location) {

    }
};
```

after

```
 myLocationChangeListener.onMyLocationChange(location);
```